# Как переписать метод из Controller в Model, yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Делал неправильно, запрос писал в методе екшн в контроллере.
Как тепер переписать его так, чтобы сам метод был в модели Content, а в контроллере actionAlbum он вызывался и рендерил вьюху return $this->render('album'). Как-то не нашёл инфу на эту тему
Код екшна

```
public function actionAlbum($id)
{

    $query = Content::find()
        ->select('content.*')
        ->with('category')
        ->where(['category_id' => $id]);

    $pagination = new Pagination(['totalCount' => $query->count(), 'pageSize'=>6]);
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'pagination' => $pagination
    ]);
    return $this->render('album', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'pagination' => $pagination,
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно или не правильно, это только вам решать.
Информация на эту тему, будет примерно называться - "Как в двух классах сделать два метода и в одном вызвать другой".
Точность реализации будет зависеть от потребностей, простой пример:

Model:

```
class Content extends AcitveRecord{
    ...

    public static function GetAlbum($id){
        $query = Content::find();

        ....

        return $var;
    }

    ...
}
```

Controller:

```
public function actionAlbum($id)
{

    $data = Content::GetAlbum($id);

    ...

    return $this->render('album', [
        'data' => $data
    ]);
}
```